# Display jQuery UI Icons properly

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I've been trying to create icon set that contains two icons, what I tried to do is import jQuery UI css files and copy html from examples, however it does not work.

Can someone help me make icons in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RKwky/) fiddle to look just like [these](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.2/tests/static/icons.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get it perfectly matching in functionality since you're losing hover/active states, but you can make it pretty close by adding some padding and setting the li to inline-block.

```
li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:.25em 0 0 .25em; /*Just for spacing in the demo*/
    padding:.25em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RKwky/3/

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some CSS to the containers and the icons:

```
li.ui-state-default {
    padding: 4px 0; /* this will add some space top/bottom */
    float: left;  /* LI is a block by default so it take full width */
    /* display: inline-block; you could also use inline-block instead of float */
}

.ui-icon {
    margin: 0 4px; /* this gives the icon left/right space */
}​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/hHwMg/)